# jstree - custom widget when editing node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jstree and each node in the tree is an email address. When I add a new email, on "rename", I would like to have for editing a specific widget, something like: @. So, I would like the @ to be a constant (that can't be changed/removed) and to have the user type in the before/after '@'.

I have searched a lot, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Maria

Answer (score 0):

I think thats impossible to do with the current jstree version. Instead on rename of a node, validate the name for email.  `(Regular Expression: *@*.* )` And alert the user if its not validated and make the name editable in your code.